key captured but not working js + shortkeys+ chrome
Added code to run js function in shortkeys extension
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

  if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 's') {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Save!');
  }
});

keys are being captured but nothing is happening
tried pressing the key combination (Ctrl+S) and was expecting an alert window from chrome with the message "Save!"

To capture the keys reliably you need to do it in the capture phase by specifying true as the third parameter of addEventListener. Also this extension probably can't handle tabs that show a built-in browser page or another extension.
